# A question regarding (ε, δ)-definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

**Definition**

> $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ means, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0; 0 < |x-a|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L|< \epsilon$, with $x, a, L \in \mathbb{R}$.

I understand this is THE definition of limit and I should follow as it is stated

But I just can't understand why it is written this way.

To me,

> $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ means, $\forall \delta >0, \exists \epsilon >0; 0 < |x-a|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L|< \epsilon$, with $x, a, L \in \mathbb{R}$

this way of writing(choosing $ \delta > 0$ first and finding corresponding $\epsilon$) seems to work as well as choosing epsilon first.

For every function I(first year in college) can think of, I can pick any delta I want FIRST and still find corresponding $\epsilon$. Rest of the definition also fits

So here's my question:
Is it possible that we choose delta first and still make it work?

Comment: No, you're given $\varepsilon>0$, and you must find a $\delta>0$ to "beat it". We want to make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$ by making $x$ close enough to $a$, not the other way around.

Comment: Let's go with your definition. Then surely $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and arbitrary $L$. The point of the limit definition is to show that the limit is specific, i.e. unique. This is where your definition fails; it doesn't prove anything.

Comment: But if $\delta > 0$ is given, can't you also find corresponding $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: If you happen choose your $\varepsilon$'s tending to zero as $\delta$ tends to zero, then great.  But what if I have a function that is arbitrary except that $-1<f(x)<1$ for all $x$?  Your definition is met if I always choose $L=0$ and $\epsilon=1$.  But really I don't know anything about any limits of that function, or even if it's continuous.

Comment: Suppose we proceed according to your version. Then we lose uniqueless of $L$. If $f(x)$ is a bounded function then your definition can be satisfied for any $L$ (example given in my answer). Please try to find out what you gain out of your way of defining limits. I am not able to guess the motivation behind your way of definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to understand the concept of limit informally. The concept is introduced to study the behavior of a function $f(x)$ when the values of $x$ are near a certain specific value say $x = a$. Our goal is to see if the values of $f(x)$ also lie near some specific value $L$ when $x$ is near $a$. This "near to" has to be as good as it is possible and hence we need to quantify them using arbitrary positive numbers like $\epsilon$.

In the definition of limit $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ we want to ensure that $f(x)$ can be made arbitrary near to $x$ by making $x$ sufficiently near to $a$. Thus the difference $|f(x) - L| $ has be made less than any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ by making $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ for some suitably chosen $\delta$ depending upon $\epsilon$. According to your version when $\delta > 0$ is arbitrary and $\epsilon > 0$ is chosen based on $\delta$ we are not guaranteeing that the difference $|f(x) - L|$ can be made as small as we would like it to be. In fact in your version we just can choose any big number $\epsilon$ without any problem and yet satisfy the inequalities you mention (unless the function is bounded). For example if $f(x) = \sin x, x = 0$ then given any $\delta > 0$ we have $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ always imply $|f(x) - L| \leq |\sin x| + |L| \leq 1 + |L| < \epsilon$ if we choose $\epsilon $ greater than $|L| + 1$. And this happens for any number $L$.

So your definition does not try to specify any property of a specific $L$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(x)$ be a function that hops crazily between $0$ and $1$, say $0$ at rationals and $1$ at irrationals. For any $\delta\gt 0$, there is an $\epsilon$, namely $17$, such that whenever $|x-a|\lt \delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$.