# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to-2}(3x^4+2x^2-x+1)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to-2}(3x^4+2x^2-x+1)$$

I have to evaluate this limit without using 'continuity ideas'. So I assume I cannot substitute $-2$ into the function and find the limit, can I? How do I go about finding this limit then?

Comment: Did you know the definition of limit??

Comment: just put the limit in place of $x$

Comment: @Alearner The $\epsilon-\delta$ argument? yes I do. Do I have to use that argument to solve this question?

Comment: @Grvsaini like this $3(-2)^4+2(-2)^2-(-2)+1$ ? Is this not based on the continuity of the limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can guess that $\lim_{x \to -2} (3x^{4}+2x^{2}-x+1)=59$ and to prove this we can use definition to show that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \: \exists \delta>0 \:\forall x\: |x-(-2)|=|x+2|<\delta$ we have

$$|3x^4+2x^2-x+1-59|=|x+2||3x^3-6x^2+14x-29|\le \varepsilon$$

then assume wlog $|x+2|<1$ that is $-3<x<-1$ then

$$|x+2||3x^3-6x^2+14x-29|\le \delta|3x^3-6x^2+14x-29| \le 206 \,\delta$$

since $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+14x-29$ is negative strictly increasing for $x\in[-3,-1]$ and $|f(-3)|=206$, then it suffices to assume

$$\delta \le \frac{\varepsilon}{206}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Finding a "suitable" $\delta$ given a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2286877/505767)
- [A question regarding (ε, δ)-definition of limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567562/505767)

Answer (score 0):

Since that
$$lim_{x \to -2} 3x^{2}=3(-2)^{4},$$
$$\lim_{x\to -2}2x^{2}=2(-2)^{2},$$
$$\lim_{x\to -2}-x=-(-2)$$and $$\lim_{x \to -2}1=1$$Therefore you can conclude that $$\lim_{x \to -2} (3x^{4}+2x^{2}-x+1)$$exists and also $$\lim_{x \to -2} (3x^{4}+2x^{2}-x+1)=3(-2)^{4}+2(-2)^{2}-(-2)+1=59.$$

Note that you only need the property's of limits.

Comment: It seems asker is looking for a proof by $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition.